# rails will_paginate with JQuery UI Tabs

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, will-paginate

I would like to know if it is possible to add pagination with will_paginate for each of the tabs in a JQuery UI Tabs.

For exemple, I have two tabs, one with ten element and one with thirty. Is it possible to add pagination for each ten elements in order to have the first tab without pagination and the second with three pages?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that is possible. All will_paginate do is generate the correct URLs for each set of resources.